# Burndown Chart Ideal/Projection

Tags: agile, burn-charts

I'm using the [redmine agile plugin online demo](http://demo.redmineup.com/projects/agile/agile/charts?query_id=29). The website advertises the plugin with a sample image for "Work Burndown" - I am trying to replicate this graph using the demo itself. The sample image from [the linked page](https://www.luisblasco.com/en/agile-plugin-redminecrm):

[image]

I'm most interested in the portion circled in red. As I understand it the "Ideal" grey colored line as you see it here extends out beyond the actual work in order to provide a projection/estimate of when the work might be finished.

As previously stated I am trying to use the online demo itself to replicate this graph and can't seem to figure it out. This is either due to lack understanding of agile/burndown or the tool itself, or both. Here is my graph from the online demo:

[image]

Notice that in my graph the "Ideal" line doesn't project out past the actual work remaining, it simply "staircases" down to meet the end of the graph. It does this no matter the date range I specify.

Any recommendations on how I can make this thing display the estimate projection like in their advertised screen shot? At the time of writing the [online demo is available here](http://demo.redmineup.com/projects/agile/agile/charts?query_id=29).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a forecast line. That is a different thing (that this tool may or may not do, not sure). In a burndown chart with a fixed set of items and a fixed timebox (like a sprint) the ideal line simply shows the mathematical ideals to complete the total work in the timebox. It is only meant as a point of reference to compare the actual to. It is always a strait line from (0,a) where a is the amount of work in the sprint to (b, 0) where b is the number of days in the sprint.

Answer (score 0):

I think your understanding of agile burndowns is fine. Daniel correctly points out, that the tool only shows a simple linear relation between the span of time and the total amount of work. This shows how much work should remain at any given point of time.

In the case of the demo it seems to also take into consideration the weekends (flat parts of the "ideal" line). For shorter time frames (e.g. the Burndown of a 1-4 week iteration) this is very useful in my experience. For longer time frames (e.g. a quarter year) it's probably insignificant.

The tool you reference, simply draws the ideal line for the time span that is displayed in the diagram. You can change the date filter setting to a custom time span to get the desired result.

[image]